# PreparedStatement doesn't change anything

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I wrote this code after an example i found on the net but it doesn't work, could you please tell me what is possibly wrong with it. It seems to do something and prints out the result but nothing changes.

```
package com.company.Start;

import java.sql.*;

public class PreparedStmt
{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@PC:1521/XE","ACCOUNT", "password");
  PreparedStatement updateDB = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Customers SET lname=? WHERE name=?");
  updateDB.setString(1, "Meier");
  updateDB.setString(2, "Peter");
  updateDB.execute();
  Statement smt = con.createStatement();
  String query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
  ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(query);
  System.out.println("NAME   LNAME   ADRESS");
  while (rs.next()) {
   String name = rs.getString("name");
   String lname = rs.getString("lname");
   System.out.println(name + " " + lname);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What result does it print? Are you sure you are checking the same DB for changes?

Comment: What is wrong with the result that it prints?

Comment: @HariShankar he's reusing the same connection so I'd say it's the same database.

Comment: there is only one DB and the result is the same as before attempting to change anything

Comment: @Thomas yea but you could also go to the db and check. Just want to make sure, because there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: Check if the name are in correct case. Also check if there are additional space character in the DB against the name.

Comment: i checked at the DB, nothing changed

Comment: What **is** the data before?

Comment: in this example lname is "Schulz" before and i want to change it to "Meier"

Comment: And it stays "Schulz"?!

Comment: And name does not have a blank in it or something? " Peter" won't match "Peter" ...

Comment: Have you tried to search explicitly for "Peter"? I suspect it isn't matched.

Comment: Can you try executing `UPDATE Customers SET lname='Meier' WHERE name='Peter'` in the DB directly?

Comment: Or do `System.out.println(updateDb.executeUpdate())` to see the number of records updated. If it says `0`, then the query does not update anything.

Comment: directly in the DB it works and yes is does give `0` so it might be a connection problem?

Comment: @nochnichda No it is a "Peter is not found" Problem ;)

Comment: Try "... WHERE name LIKE ?" and for value put "%Peter%"

Comment: Could it be a case sensitivity problem? Somewhere case sensitivity is turned on? Is it "peter" in the DB?

Comment: @Fildor
you're right that **was** the problem 
can you give it as an answer so i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "... WHERE name LIKE ?" and for value put "%Peter%"

I guess the name is not matched, because there is a blank or something.

Mind that the above will also change entries like "Peter-Alexander" or "Hans-Peter".
So this is just a prove that it is the value not being matched exactly.

Comment: i guess it is because the column allows more chars than "Peter" consists of

Comment: How the heck did it work when you ran it directly on the database then?!

Comment: i dont know but with the whitespace added in the code it works

Answer (score 0):

Try using `updateDB.executeUpdate()` instead of `updateDB.execute()` . Strangely `execute` does not work for data updates in most of the cases.

Comment: it doesnt change anything

Comment: @nochnichda are u getting some exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine.
What is the value (int) returned by `updateDB.executeUpdate();`?
What does a DB utility (like SQLFront) produce given the same statement?
Try `con.setAutoCommit(true);` and `updateDB.close();`

Comment: @nochnichda
This means that your statement doesn't change anything in the database, i.e. the fault is that there is no name "Peter" in your DB. This is not a java problem.